# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'bool' although info doesn't have bool in sklearn column transformer

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, supervised-learning

There are similar questions asked before on stackoverflow, however, none of them could fix my problem. I don't understand why info() clearly doesn't output a "bool" but sklearn is outputting an error saying I have boolean values in my dataframe. Can anyone help me debug this thanks!

```
X = df.drop("Transported", axis=1)
y = df.Transported
X.info()
"""
output:
>>> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 8693 entries, 0 to 8692
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------        --------------  -----  
 0   HomePlanet    8492 non-null   object 
 1   CryoSleep     8476 non-null   object 
 2   Cabin         8494 non-null   object 
 3   Destination   8511 non-null   object 
 4   Age           8514 non-null   float64
 5   VIP           8490 non-null   object 
 6   RoomService   8512 non-null   float64
 7   FoodCourt     8510 non-null   float64
 8   ShoppingMall  8485 non-null   float64
 9   Spa           8510 non-null   float64
 10  VRDeck        8505 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(6), object(5)
memory usage: 747.2+ KB
"""
categorical_features = ["HomePlanet", "CryoSleep", "Cabin", "Destination", "VIP"]
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="constant", fill_value="missing")),
    ("encoder", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"))
])
numerical_features = ["Age", "RoomService", "FoodCourt", "ShoppingMall", "Spa", "VRDeck"]
numerical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="median")),
    ("scaler", StandardScaler())
])
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ("cat", categorical_transformer, categorical_features),
    ("num", numerical_transformer, numerical_features)
])
model = Pipeline(steps=[("preprocessor", preprocessor), ("model", RandomForestRegressor())])
X = df.drop("Transported", axis=1)
y = df["Transported"]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
model.score(X_test, y_test)
```

error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File D:\Programming\python\machine_learning\ml\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_encode.py:173, in _unique_python(values, return_inverse, return_counts)
    171 uniques_set, missing_values = _extract_missing(uniques_set)
--> 173 uniques = sorted(uniques_set)
    174 uniques.extend(missing_values.to_list())

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'bool'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [68], in <cell line: 19>()
     17 y = df["Transported"]
     18 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
---> 19 model.fit(X_train, y_train)
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing is, columns like `CryoSleep` and `VIP` are actually boolean (I assume this is the original Kaggle ST dataset). They're shown as `object` because of missing values (resulting in a mixed type).

Try explicitly changing the values first, e.g.:

```
   df['CryoSleep'] = str(df['CryoSleep'])
   df['VIP'] = str(df['VIP'])
```

On a minor note, you probably meant using `RandomForestClassifier()`.